# Why is the question about LOLCODE closed as "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion

I recently [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262409/is-there-a-lolcode-compiler) on the StackOverflow if there is a native LOLCODE compiler available on the Internet. Honestly, I was shocked to find that after few days the question was closed as "off-topic".

Don't you think it is overzealous?
Those guys who voted for that thread to be closed obviously did not even bother to learn anything about LOLCODE, they probably just went to the website, saw an example of a (VALID!) LOLCODE program, and thought "this is a joke".

For their information, there are over 20 interpreters for LOLCODE (now perhaps even more). Yes, it is a funny programming language (that was the whole point of making it), but is a **programming language**.

To back-up what I've just said, please take a look at [LOLCODE implementations](http://lolcode.com/implementations/implementations). You will see a compiler that targets .NET ( http://lolcode.com/, implementations/lolcode.net ), a very efficient LOLCODE interpreter written in C ( http://www.icanhaslolcode.org/ ), interpreters written in Python, JavaScript, Java, and many others.

My question would be the same as "Is there a native Ruby compiler which targets x86 or x86_64 available?". I am 100% sure the question about Ruby compiler would not be closed. So, why this discrimination?

I think there should be more control over who can close a thread. Or, perhaps a way to measure "objectiveness" of S.O. members, so I can vote down objectiveness of those who closed the abovementioned thread.

Comment: To what end would you want an "objectiveness" vote - so people who get downvoted a lot eventually lose their voting privileges? But who controls the objectiveness of those downvotes, which can (and probably will) be entirely subjective? Seriously though, just vote to reopen. I just did

Comment: The question has been reopened now.

Comment: @Pekka, maybe I should have spent more time formalising what I wanted to say. Anyhow, you have a good point...

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @UphillLuge How is that relevant? This isn't "Macbook Air vs. Macbook Pro?" it's "I need a method of making my Macbook work in a certain way". It's the exact reason we have Q & A sites.